# How to clear the GPU memory of a layer in TensorFlow framework?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am just using TensorFlow to realise a CNN model. During the training process, there is an intermediate variable which occupies a large GPU memory and I want to clear the memory of this variable when it is not used in the following layers.

How could I achieve this in TensorFlow? Thanks in advance!

There is an intermediate variable which occupies a large GPU memory in my model and I want to clear its memory. This variable is called 'rgb_concat', I just tried to use 'rgb_concat=[]' to clear its memory, not sure if it is useful in TensorFlow?

```
    x = input_image
    for j in range(n_sub_layers):
        nn = Conv2dLayer(x, j)     #
        rgb_concat.append(nn)
        x = nn
    rgb_concat_sublayer = ConcatLayer([rgb_concat[0], rgb_concat[1]], concat_dim=3, name='rgb_concat_sublayer_{}_{}'.format(i,1))
    for sub_layer in range(2, n_sub_layers): #Second 'for' loop!!!
            rgb_concat_sublayer = ConcatLayer([rgb_concat_sublayer, rgb_concat[sub_layer]], concat_dim=3, name='rgb_concat_sublayer_{}_{}'.format(i,sub_layer))
```

After the second 'for' loop, I do not need 'rgb_concat' anymore and I want to clear the memory of it after the second 'for' loop. How could I achieve this?

The occupied GPU memory of 'rgb_concat' should be clear after second 'for' loop. Could I use 'rgb_concat=[]' after the second 'for' loop to realise this? Thanks!